# image slider needs to work on scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I'm trying to create vertical image slider with thumbnail navigation which can be work on mouse wheel also. I have achieved that slider with "jquery flexslider" plugin. Now I need that image slider should work on "scroll" & navigation works accordingly.

Please check the attached image as expected result. Scroll should recognized the slider container and slide the images. Once finished all the images it should scroll rest of the page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the `wheel` event which will tell you when the mousewheel or touchpad scroll is used over an element. Then you can use `preventDefault()` to conditionally prevent vertical scrolling depending on if the user is flipping through the image gallery. You should be able to figure out the rest from there. :)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel